# iOS popup/splash screen with external web content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to display a popup or something like a splash screen every time I start my app. The content of this popup must be taken from an external web source (something like jpg, png or pdf).
The purpose of this popup is to warn users about news and special offers. The popup should disappear after a certain time (or at the pressure of a button).

From what I read on other threads, the UIPopoverController feature seems be helpful for what I need (as I read in this class reference), but I'm afraid that the main function of this popup is presenting a choice in result of the pressure of a button.

Comment: If you do this, **PLEASE** check to make sure you have an internet connection before displaying the view. So many apps don't and the app fails :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can you not simply add a webview to the screen when the app opens?

Like:

in appDelegate:

```
UIWebview *popover;

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     UIWindow *win = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

     popover = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:win.bounds];

     ... load content ...

     [win addSubview:popover];


     [self performSelector:@selector(dismissPopover) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

-(void)dismissPopover
{
     [popover removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: One more question: (I'm pretty new to objective C) where I must declare `UIWebview *popover;` ? In AppDelegate.h I presume... right? (BTW I'm using ARC). Thank you

Comment: if your planning on accessing it outside the AppDelegate for whatever reason, like in a viewController, then yes make it a property of the AppDelegate. If its not to be accessed outside the current file then add it as a private variable by declaring it in the implementation: @implementation AppDelegate{
    UIWebView *webView;
}

...

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive: .....

Comment: Well explained. Thank you Simon.